# How do I create an ActiveStorage::Blob from an existing S3 object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I have objects that are uploaded to S3 using multipart uploads. I am unable to edit the code that uploads the object to S3. I want to create an `ActiveStorage` attachment to connect this S3 object and others to their own respective records.

I began by creating an `ActiveStorage::Blob` manually with:

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.create(
  key: <key of S3 object>,
  filename: <name of file>,
  content_type: "application/zip",
  service_name: <my S3 service name>,
  byte_size: <fake byte size, this is not used>
)
```

From there, I was hoping I could finally create the attachment, but I am unable to create a `Blob` without the checksum. How do I compute the checksum for the S3 object when I create this Blob object and then attach the blob to a record?

Comment: Where’s the checksum field in that constructor? Also do you mean checksum? Is each file split into different parts?